# Getting data from span class in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to data scraping and I am using `BeautifulSoup` to grap some data from a webpage.

What I have done is the following

```
all = soup.find_all("span",{"class":"compare-property"})

arg=all[0]

print(arg)
```

The output is:

```
< span class="compare-property" data-placement="top" data-propid="1858251"    data-toggle="tooltip" id="compare-link-1858251" title="Bera saman">
< i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
< /span>'
```

Now I need the number called `data-propid`, which is 1858251 in the example
How can I get that number?

Comment: `arg.get("data-propid")` should do the trick

Comment: is there only one element with that class (compare-property) on the page?

Comment: No there are many elements. I wish to loop through them all.
Thanks, arg.get("data-propid") did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get it with

```
all[0]['data-propid']
```

Greetings
Kai Dannies

Answer (score 1):

You can just access the attribute of the element.

```
all = soup.find_all("span",{"class":"compare-property"})

arg=all[0]

print(arg['data-propid'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the beautiful soup documentation here:
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

You want:

```
for link in soup.find_all("span",{"class":"compare-property"}):
    print(link.get('data-propid'))
```